# How to add custom username in Slack API files.upload using bot user?

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I am uploading a file using `files.upload` method and want to display username like XYZ or any other custom username (which works in `chat.postMessage`).

Below code is working, file is uploading but in response `username` returns empty and in Slack message displays with app name **Demo App**.

```
response = slack.api_call(
                'files.upload',
                channels='#website',
                file=io.BytesIO(file.read()),
                title='File from slack api',
                initial_comment='Create by XYZ',
                username='XYZ',
            )
```

When posting text message it is working fine and displaying same name I mention in `username`

```
response = slack.api_call(
            'chat.postMessage',
            channel='#website',
            text='This is from slack demo',
            username='ABC'            
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a feature that the this Slack API method offers. If you share a file is will always be showing the name of the actual token owner who uploaded it. Which may be a bot user or real user.